# how to take N space separated inputs from user in python?

Tags: python, input, space

for ex:

N = 3

1 2 3 (#inputs of length N)

#so I need to take 3 inputs from the user because N value is 3

Comment: Strings have a method "split" for this.

Comment: inp = input("Enter N numbers:\n").split()
# This gives you N space separated inputs in the list 'inp'
inp = [int(i) for i in inp]
# This will convert all inputs to integer